# FFmpeg encoding mjpeg cannot be played by other players

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using the following to encode a stream of images:

```
ffmpeg -y -i pipe: -f mjpeg -r 60 -probesize 42M -s 1280x720 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/60/TB  -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  -b:v 5505K -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

The resulting video can only be played by ffplay. It is not a problem of pixel format as suggested in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/704744/video-produced-from-images-only-plays-in-vlc-but-no-other-players).
As explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/760056/receiving-ffmpeg-error-22-when-piping-data-to-stdout), ffmpeg does not write a header in case of streaming.

However, if I'm pipeing it to another ffmpeg process the output is fine and can be played with any player:

```
ffmpeg -y -i pipe: -f mjpeg -r 60 -probesize 42M -s 1280x720 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/60/TB  -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  -b:v 5505K -pix_fmt yuv420p -f nut pipe: | ffmpeg -y -i pipe: -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

How to get a video file without the second ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding H.264 using the `libx264` encoder, not `mjpeg`.

<strike>`-f mjpeg` is for a raw bitstream and will only select the `mjpeg` encoder if `-c:v` is *not* specified. You probably want a regular container like Quicktime MOV to hold the stream.</strike>

Use

`ffmpeg -y -f mjpeg -i pipe:0 -r 60 -s 1280x720 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/60/TB -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 5505K -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Comment: True, I am not encoding using mjpeg. mjpeg is the input and I'm encoding to h264. This is what i need to encode to h264.